# HTML tags listed by natural display type

Tags: css, html

Does anyone know where to find a list of HTML tags grouped by their natural display type... ie a list of HTML tags that naturally display as inline and a list of tags that naturally display as block?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

[List of Inline elements](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html)

[List of Block elements](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html)